# Can not seem to find last four spaceship parts

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

[image: GTA 5 numbered spaceship parts map]

I had 18 spaceship parts. I can't find part 47, 48, 49 and 50. I play on PS3. How can I obtain the last four parts?

Comment: what games is this? while most likely the tag for the game you are talking about doesn't exists the fact you don't even mention it makes it impossible for us to help fix the question

Comment: The map is for GTA 5. It has a collection quest for 50 spaceship parts.

Answer (score 1):

part 47 - This Spaceship part is located in the hidden marijuana farm just to the north of Grapeseed. Take the road leading to farm and you'll find the case inside the empty farmhouse.

part 48 - This Spaceship part is located in the forest in Paleto Bay. Look for a large tree log above a concrete waterway. The case is inside the concrete waterway.

part 49 - This Spaceship part is located in a multistory firetower. Take the stairs and you'll find the case on the third floor.

part 50 - This Spaceship part is located at the Donkey Punch farm in Paleto Bay. The case is inside the main shed at the back.